# Access Subreport compare records

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an Access database that tracks employees and positions in the department. A part of this will be the requirements (hardware, software, and permissions) for each position. When an employee changes positions, there is a report that should list the requirements of both the old and new positions.

The data is:

- Position (Position Code is PK, Dept, Loc)
- Requirement (one table for each requirement category, with an appropriate PK and Description)
- Linking table for each requirement (3 fields: PK + FK from Positions and the matching requirement table).

So, for example, employee A transfers from Position 1 to Position 2.

- Position 1 has access to network folders aaa and bbb
- Position 2 has access to network folders bbb and ccc

I would like these two lists to display side-by-side with the items common to both lists hidden.
I would like the report to display:

- Add Network Access: ccc
- Remove Network Access: aaa

I have not yet found a way to accomplish this. Can anyone help? Thank you
It is 6 months later, and still no resolution. 
I am still hopeful that this can be done.

Comment: I have tried two queries to get access for the "old" and "new" positions. When I compare, I get "aaa", "bbb", and "ccc" because each does not match one of the other two. DISTINCT prevented the duplication of "aaa" and "ccc".  I am not sure how to only get the values that do not match any of the other values.

Comment: I tried nesting subreports and that did not work.

Comment: Create the query first, then attach to subform..

Comment: I have tried that approach, yet the results are the same.

Comment: Good, but if so, you shold show the query you tried and didn't make up to you. Edit your post to add your actual efforts